# Communication between programs

Tags: java

I have 2 general questions here:

Firstly, say I have 2 java programs running. Almost like a responder and an executor.

The executor can issues commands, requests and the such from the responder. I know it is possible to have them both packed as one program through multi-threading, but necessarily there might not be just 1 responder, there could be 3, maybe even 0 responders.

What is the best way for the 2 programs to 'communicate' such as a stream, implying I have no access to the other adapters? 

The second question:

Is there a way to check to see if a Java program is open already? So if I run a program, I can't run it a second time if the first is still running.

Thanks

Comment: On *nix systems you have named pipes, which could probably be used as streams in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You must explicitly code a socket-based solution. Today I guess REST would be the most obvious choice. A more heavyweight solution would be something JMS-based (involving a standalone message queue, also socked-based).
2. Yes, there is a way, but nothing out of the box. It usually involves creating temporary files that are checked for existence. There are some handy methods provided, like `createTemporaryFile` and `deleteOnExit` that take care of the low-level work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pick the level of communication between programs.
In Java the lowest level of communication would be through Socket API.
On top of it there's a bunch of other protocols implemented: RMI, Corba, various web services, etc.

In order to ensure 1 instance running you have to rely on something outside of that instance. I can think of:

- External file created by running app.
- Database record produced by running app.
- Port open by your running app.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for both of your question can be using Sockets

1- For communication, a multi-threaded client/server application can be a good solution

2- To check if the program is already running, as a workaround (beside using files) you can listen to a certain port so if another instance of the program failed to listen to this port it means that the program is already running.

You can store the port that you listen to in a file, instead of hardcoding it, to avoid possible conflict with other applications that might use the same port by chance.